# Where is the fob receiver located in the 2005 Mazda 3?

Tags: mazda, locks, mazda-3, fob, central-locking

I have a 2005 Mazda Mazda3 hatchback, for which the key fob remote lock/unlock has an increasingly short range.

I've read [@Edward](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/14098/edward)'s excellent [answer to *Remote does not always lock/unlock the car: diagnosing RF receiver issues*](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/29534). I'm at the stage where I'd like to know where specifically the RF receiver for the remote fob is located.

I did not find this information in the owner's manual, but it's not the sort of information I'd expect an owner's manual to cover.  Nor did a web search pan out for me.

Can anyone tell me where to look?

Comment: "increasingly short range": Sounds like the battery in the fob is going dead. Have you tried replacing it?

Comment: Yes. Replacing the fob's battery is #1 on @Edward's excellent answer. I'm past that, to the further steps on that answer. Those involve knowing where the RF receiver is. And, the battery I took out of the fob has the same voltage as a new battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These threads seem to suggest it's located to the rear of the dome light, behind the headliner.

http://www.mazda3forums.com/57-mazda3-axela/631290-keyless-entry-module-2006-sedan-where.html

https://www.mazda3club.com/mazda3-mazdaspeed3-98/where-keyless-entry-control-module-2004-mazda-3-a-55843/